# Why does text disapear when I add font family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Why does the text disappear in the output when I declare a font-family to the header in CSS ( `.heading { }` ) ?

Before:
[Before font-family declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui09I.png)

After:
[After font-family declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXeh9.png)

---

Another similar but stranger issue with the font-family declaration was that after the declaration was added the Text would not adhere to the margin, padding, and border specifications, and would overlap with the floated `<div>`. This problem would persist even if the line was deleted, and only fixed when the file changes were reversed using "ctrl + Z".

---

Code:

```css
* {
    
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
              box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    
    .clearfix {
     overflow: auto;
    }

    @page{
    
     size: 7in 9.25in;
     margin: 27mm 16mm 27mm 16mm; 
    
    }
    
    #margin {
     max-width: 90%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .sectionHeadingIndent {
    
     background-color: black;
     border: black;
     float: left;
     width: 5%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    ***Font-family declaration below here***
    
    .heading {
    
     margin-left: 5%;
     padding-left: 1%;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     padding-bottom: 0;
     border-bottom-style: none;
     font-family: Courier;
    }
    
    .header {
     position: relative
    }
    
    .header_firstLine {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     padding-bottom: 0;
     border-bottom-style: none;
    }
    
    .header_secondLine {
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 5%;
     padding-left: 1%;
     margin-top: 0;
     padding-top: 0;
    
     line-height: 1;
     border-top-style: none;
    
    }
    
    #introduction {
     height: 20%;
    }
    
    .Subhead {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    
    #objective_summary{
     width: 30%;
     margin: 10% auto;
    }
```

```html
 
    <!-- Page boundary div -->
    <div>
    
     <!-- Margins div -->
     <div id = "margin" >
    
    
      <section id = "introduction">
      <!-- Introduction section -->
    
       <div class = "header">
    
        <div class = "header_firstLine">
         <!-- For indent and Name -->
         <div class = "sectionHeadingIndent"></div>
    
         <h1 class = "heading", style = "arial">H1</h1>
        </div>
    
        <div class = "header_secondLine clearfix">
         <!-- For Contact Information -->
         <div class = "Subhead">
          Subheading
         </div>
    
    
        </div>
    
       <div id = "objective_summary">
        Text
       </div>
    
      </section>
    
    
      <section>
      <!-- on Section -->
       <div class = "header">
        <div class = "sectionHeadingIndent"></div>
    
        <h2 class = "heading">H2</h2>
       </div>
    
    
       <div>
    
        <div class = "on_ce">
         <div class = "on_name">
          Text
         </div>
         <div class = "on_place">
          Text
         </div>
        </div>
    
       </div>
    
      </section>
    
    
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I removed " ***Font-family declaration below here*** " from your code and everything seems to be working fine.  When using comments in css it should look like this:  /* This is a comment */

Comment: No worries @kishan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly copy and pasting, your code works fine *after removing the comment*.

However, your code also contains an error. A comma was used:

```
<h1 class = "heading", style = "arial">H1</h1>
-->
<h1 class = "heading" style = "arial">H1</h1>
```

Comment: Strange direct copy and paste does not work for me. Can you think of anything that could account for the discrepancy ?

(Thanks for pointing out that error. I am new to this, and that was also an incomplete attempt at debugging.)

Comment: Only thing I can come up with right now is a corrupted font file. Have you tried another font such as Times New Roman or Arial? Make sure to remove your comment in the CSS or else the headers won't work.

Comment: Actually that was another issue that I was having and the reason for the debug attempt which led to the error you pointed out. At that time no other common font except for Courier was working.

Right now strangely with your fix and trav's comment above made my test file work like expected, but not the original.